# logic of shifting 0 4 times in efr32 cmuClock_GPIO setting

Tags: microcontroller

in the variable bellow cmuClock of gpio is defined.
i know what is << and bit wise or operations .
but there are logical stuff like shifting 0 four times :-)
shifting 0 4 times still will result in zero.
What kind of registers are used in efr32 for this purpose?
Thanks.

```
cmuClock_GPIO = (CMU_NOPRESC_REG << CMU_PRESC_REG_POS)//0<<4
                  | (CMU_NOSEL_REG << CMU_SEL_REG_POS)//0<<0
                  | (CMU_HFBUSCLKEN0_EN_REG << CMU_EN_REG_POS)//5<<8
                  | (_CMU_HFBUSCLKEN0_GPIO_SHIFT << CMU_EN_BIT_POS)//2<<12
                  | (CMU_HFBUS_CLK_BRANCH << CMU_CLK_BRANCH_POS),//5<<17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing it this way makes the code maintainable.

If the value of `CMU_NOPRESC_REG` needs to change to something other than zero, you can just change one constant in one place, and the code still works.

If you take away the shift, then when you want to change the value of that bitfield then you can't just change one constant, you have to go through all the code and put the shifts back in.

(Note also that if you write `(0 << N)` then the compiler will never actually generate a shift instruction anyway, it will do the shift at compile time and insert the resulting value in the binary).

Comment: Hello Tom, What is the name of the register they are trying to set?
i cant see a clear name.I am using EFR32 MCU what kind of register the bitfield or operation goes into?

Comment: I haven't used this exact micro, but `_Pos` is a common suffix for bitfield position within a register in all kinds of cortex microcontroller headers, so I guess the field is called CMU_NOPRESC.  You can find the name of all the registers and bitfields if you read the header file that is included in the source file where you found this code.  You can find what they mean and how to use them in the datasheet or manual for the exact part.

Comment: Hello Tom,The full file including the cmuClock_gpio definition i posted is in teh attached link bellow.
I know that the bitwise result is 664832.
howcan i know where to look in this file and see what register is being set?
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VbTY_57pOvZNPP3osnFerNgHEiLkSSAAX0a_flAxiw0/edit?usp=sharing

reference manual:
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg12-rm.pdf

Comment: This isn't writing to a register, this is defining a member of an enum.  Presumably the value then gets written to a register at runtime somewhere else.